# Str attribute error when using .apply() on a pandas series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apply

I have a df as follows:

```
data = {'Internal':  ['unpaid second interator 4,000 USD and $50 third', '35 $ unpaid', "all good"],
        'Name': ['Charlie', 'Rodolf', 'samuel']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print (df)
```

I would like to run this formula with .apply():

```
def unspent(row):
    if row['Internal'].str.contains('unspent',case=False)==True:
        val="unspent in text"
    else:
        val="unspent is NOT in text"
    return val
```

& get a table with an additional column:

```
df['Unspent']=df.apply(unspent,axis=1)
```

but I get an error instead:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I have tried ommiting `.str.` in the formula `def unspent` and get another error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're trying to use `str.contains` which is a pandas Series method on a string (because `row['Internal']` is a string for every `row`)

What you can do is either replace

```
if row['Internal'].str.contains('unspent',case=False)==True:
```

with

```
if 'unspent' in row['Internal']:
```

in your function or use `str.contains` on the `df['Internal']` column to create a boolean series and use `np.where` to select values:

```
df['Unspent'] = np.where(df['Internal'].str.contains('unspent', case=False), "unspent in text", "unspent is NOT in text")
```

Output:

```
                                 Internal     Name  \
0  unpaid second interator 4,000 USD and $50 third  Charlie   
1                                      35 $ unpaid   Rodolf   
2                                         all good   samuel   

                  Unspent  
0  unspent is NOT in text  
1  unspent is NOT in text  
2  unspent is NOT in text
```